# This a question about nifi jolt transformation for grouping json arrays based on a key attribute into new array

Tags: json, transform, apache-nifi, jolt

I am new to JOLT transformation, I trying to group the following JSON array
objects base on `ACCOUNTNUMBER` and `ZIP`, then aggregating the rest of the
attributes into respective roles with JOLT Transformation.
Please help me in writing the JOLT Spec to group the JSON objects to get the
output given below.

INPUT:

```json
[
  {
    "ClientCode": "1234567",
    "Relationships": [
      {
        "ENTITYID": 35056,
        "COUNTYCODE": 19,
        "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "1803",
        "ROLETYPE": "Payer",
        "ROLESEQNUM": 1,
        "ZIP": 55111
      },
      {
        "ENTITYID": 35056,
        "COUNTYCODE": 19,
        "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "1803",
        "ROLETYPE": "Owner",
        "ROLESEQNUM": 1,
        "ZIP": 55111
      },
      {
        "ENTITYID": 35056,
        "COUNTYCODE": 19,
        "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "1803",
        "ROLETYPE": "Insured",
        "ROLESEQNUM": 1,
        "ZIP": 55111
      },
      {
        "ENTITYID": 35056,
        "COUNTYCODE": 19,
        "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "1538",
        "ROLETYPE": "Payer",
        "ROLESEQNUM": 1,
        "ZIP": 54333
      },
      {
        "ENTITYID": 35056,
        "COUNTYCODE": 19,
        "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "1538",
        "ROLETYPE": "Owner",
        "ROLESEQNUM": 1,
        "ZIP": 54333
      },
      {
        "ENTITYID": 35056,
        "COUNTYCODE": 19,
        "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "1538",
        "ROLETYPE": "Insured",
        "ROLESEQNUM": 1,
        "ZIP": 54333
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

OUTPUT:

```json
[
  {
    "ClientCode": "1249612",
    "Relationships": [
      {
        "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "1803",
        "ZIP": 55111,
        "roles": [
          {
            "ENTITYID": 35056,
            "COUNTYCODE": 19,
            "ROLETYPE": "Payer",
            "ROLESEQNUM": 1
          },
          {
            "ENTITYID": 35056,
            "COUNTYCODE": 19,
            "ROLETYPE": "Owner",
            "ROLESEQNUM": 1
          },
          {
            "ENTITYID": 35056,
            "COUNTYCODE": 19,
            "ROLETYPE": "Insured",
            "ROLESEQNUM": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "1538",
        "ZIP": 54333,
        "roles": [
          {
            "ENTITYID": 35056,
            "COUNTYCODE": 19,
            "ROLETYPE": "Payer",
            "ROLESEQNUM": 1
          },
          {
            "ENTITYID": 35056,
            "COUNTYCODE": 19,
            "ROLETYPE": "Owner",
            "ROLESEQNUM": 1
          },
          {
            "ENTITYID": 35056,
            "COUNTYCODE": 19,
            "ROLETYPE": "Insured",
            "ROLESEQNUM": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can figure it out through the following **shift** transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ClientCode": "ClientCode",
        "Relationships": {
          "*": {
            "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "&2.[&1].&",
            "ZIP": "&2.[&1].&",
            "*": "&2.[&1].roles[0].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where *asterisked* keys are used to incur every subobjects, and `&2`s represent the key stated two level up from the current position(eg.`Relationships`), `[&1]`s combines one-to-one the elements of the formed arrays, `roles[0]`s stand for putting the rest of the elements other than our selected ones to the new array called `roles`, and the rightmost *ampersands* represent the innermost key-value pairs.